# Very high disk usage due to reading from CbsPersist...log

Tags: windows-7, performance, io

My personal laptop is Windows 7, Dell, 8 CPU Cores and 8GB of RAM.

It operates very slowly, especially when launching software, and I think especially  when starting up (but not only).

Looking at Resource Monitor very often shows very high disk usage. Sorting by `Total (B/sec)` shows the following entry at the top:

```
System     4     C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_<some_number>.log
```

[image]

It has a `Write (B/sec)` value of 0, but the highest `Read (B/sec)` of all. This seems to be what is choking up the disk and making things go very slow. Otherwise in the machine, CPU and RAM usage is low. Network is sometimes high too.

What is this rouge entity which chokes the disk? What can I do?

**UPDATE**

Using the Sysinternals `handle64.exe` utility, I can see that the process which holds a handle to the huge CbsPersist file is `wermgr`. What does this mean?

Comment: Try the fix in [Windows 7 log file compression bug can fill up your hard drive | Computerworld](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3112358/windows-7-log-file-compression-bug-can-fill-up-your-hard-drive.html)